# UI saying my observableArray().length == 0 one minute, then == 1 the next?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js. I declare 2 model objects:

1)

```
var model =
{
    products: ko.observableArray([])
}
```

2)

```
var customerModel = 
{
    cart: ko.observableArray([]),
    filteredProducts: ko.observableArray([]),
    currentView: ko.observable("list")
}
```

when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready
(
    function () {
        getProducts();
    }
);
```

it calls getProducts which sets the model.products observable array to have a single object:

```
var getProducts = function () {

    model.products.removeAll();
    model.products.push
    (
        {
            Id: 1,
            Name: "Product 1",
            Description: "A nice product",
            Price: 666.66,
            Category: "Category 1"
        }
    )
}
```

i have a view that renders an ASP.NET partial view. the default customerModel.currentView is 'list' (as seen from the model object i declared):

```
<div data-bind="visible: customerModel.currentView() == 'list'">
    @Html.Partial("ProductList")
</div>
```

in the partial view (ProductList.cshtml) is the following code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: model.products()">
    <span data-bind="text: $data.Description"></span>
    <button data-bind="click: addToCart">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

clicking on the button invokes the addToCart function which adds a product to the cart and sets the view:

```
var addToCart = function (product) {
    var cart = customerModel.cart;
    cart().push
    (
        {
            product: product,
            count: 1
        }
    );
    setView('cart');
}
```

setView is like this:

```
var setView = function (view) {
    customerModel.currentView(view);
}
```

when set to 'cart', the following code renders a partial view:

```
<div data-bind="visible: customerModel.currentView() == 'cart'">
    @Html.Partial("ProductCart")
</div>
```

now HERE is the kicker. ProductCart.cshtml looks like this:

```
<script>
    var testCart = function () {
        alert("There is " + customerModel.cart().length + " item incustomerModel.cart()");
    }
</script>

<div data-bind="if: customerModel.cart().length == 0">There are no items in customerModel.cart( </div>
<button data-bind="click: testCart">Test Cart</button>
```

so guess what? the div that says "There are no items in customerModel" shows up because customerModel.cart().length == 0, however when i click the button the alert tells me that customerModel.cart().length is equal to 1.

Comment: Without looking too closely at your code, `cart().push` sems wrong. You're materializing the `cart` observable array to a regular array, adding an item to this regular array, and then discarding it.

Comment: that's what the problem was! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to change `cart().push` to `cart.push`, as you are doing with `model.products`.

Thats how `observableArray`s work. See [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html).

When you call `cart()`, it returns a new array, with the values inside the observable. You are pushing your new value to that array, which is being lost in limbo.

You need to call the `push` method through the `ko.observableArray` API, this way it will notify all subscribers for that change, and the new value will be added to the `observableArray`.